# making a bar graph in matlib

Tags: python, graph

this is my first time using matlib and we are expected to create a bar graph based on a given data set. i have been working on this for about an hour and i was wondering if someone could set me in the right direction.

```
    def plotBarChart(u, p, g):
        bar1 = pyplot.bar(u[0], u[1], width=1, color='blue', align='center')
        bar2 = pyplot.bar(u[0], u[2], width=1, color='red', align='center')
        bar3 = pyplot.bar(u[0], u[3], width=1, color='green',     align='center')

        bar4 = pyplot.bar(p[0], p[1], width=1, color='blue', align='center')
        bar5 = pyplot.bar(p[0], p[2], width=1, color='red', align='center')
        bar6 = pyplot.bar(p[0], p[3], width=1, color='green', align='center')

        bar7 = pyplot.bar(g[0], g[1], width=1, color='blue', align='center')
        bar8 = pyplot.bar(g[0], g[2], width=1, color='red', align='center')
        bar9 = pyplot.bar(g[0], g[3], width=1, color='green', align='center')

        pyplot.legend((bar1, bar2, bar3, bar4, bar5, bar6, bar7, bar8, bar9), ('2012', '2013', '2014'), loc=1)
        pyplot.xticks(pos3, names)

        pyplot.ylabel('Amount of Students Enrolled')
        pyplot.setp(pyplot.xticks()[1], rotation=15)
        pyplot.axis([u[0], g[0], 0, 35000])
        pyplot.show()

    def main():
        u = ['Undergraduate', 30147, 29440, 29255]
        p = ['Professional', 946, 941, 947]
        g = ['Graduate', 8163, 8407, 8568]
        plotBarChart(u, p, g)
    main()
```

the program is supposed to run main and take the given data and create the bar graph from said data. i know bar graphs can be done through loops too but i didnt want to get into that to much if i didnt have to. they gave us a sample output image where there are three sets of three bars, one being labeled undergrad and consisting of the u data, one being labeled professional and consisting of the p data, and one labeled graduate which has the g data. the y axis extends from 0-35000 and the x axis is "undergraduate, professional, graduate" i just need to know where i am going wrong because it continually gives me the error that bar height must be less then 13 or scaler.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  It uses the array function from numpy instead of a for loop.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotBarChart(u, p, g):

    # set bar index array and select a width for each bar
    bar_index = np.array([1, 2, 3])
    bar_width = 0.25

    # plot all bars for each index
    bars1 = plt.bar(bar_index, u, bar_width, color = 'b', label = 'Undergrad')
    bars2 = plt.bar(bar_index + bar_width, p, bar_width, color = 'r', label = 'Professional')
    bars3 = plt.bar(bar_index + 2 * bar_width, g, bar_width, color = 'g', label = 'Grad')

    # set labels and display plot
    plt.title('')
    plt.xlabel('')
    plt.ylabel('')
    plt.xticks(bar_index + 1.5 * bar_width, ['2012', '2013', '2014'])
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

def main():
    # plot data
    undergrad = [30147, 29440, 29255]
    prof = [946, 941, 947]
    grad = [8163, 8407, 8568]
    plotBarChart(undergrad, prof, grad)

main()
```

Hope this helps!